# How to implement “ show sub-checkbox” in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I'm using object oriented php or prep statement to bind all the list of medical test from the database, my question is on how to implement the show subcheckbox in php? If checkbox of the laboratory is clicked all sub-checkbox is shown? I think javascript doesn't work

Well here's the php code for medical test checkboxes

```
  <?php
    $tsql = "select medTestName from medtest";
    $tstmt = $con->prepare($tsql);
    $tstmt->execute();
    $tstmt->bind_result($mtn);
    $tstmt->store_result();

    while ($tstmt->fetch()){
    $d1= '<input type="checkbox" name="test[]"
     value="'.$mtn.'">'.$mtn.'<br>';
    echo $d1;
    }       

    ?>
```

Here's the code for sub-checkboxes

```
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="1"><span>Complete Blood Count</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="2"><span>Blood Typing</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="3"><span>Urinalysis</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="4"><span>RPR/TPHA</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="5"><span>Hepatitis B screening</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="6"><span>Fasting Blood Sugar</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="7"><span>Creatinine</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="8"><span>Total Cholesterol(Low Cholesterol, High Cholesterol)</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="9"><span>Triglyceride</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="10"><span>VLDL</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="11"><span>Blood Uric Acid</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="12"><span>Anti-HAV Igm Screening</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="13"><span>Anti HBaAg</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="14"><span>Drug & Alcohol Test</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="15"><span>Stool Culture</span></div>
```

Here's what my medical test looks like

[image]

Here's what my database for medical test

[image]

Sorry for the long post, I really don't know what to do really :(

Comment: Vista - to confirm, you want to check the Laboratory checkbox, then the other checkboxes get shown below?

Comment: yes below the laboratory if possible :(

Comment: Ok, the way to do this is to use javascript, you said you think javascript won't work? Have you tried it yet? or do you not want to use it? Javascript will be the only way to make it work without reloading the page.

Comment: either you preload sub checkboxes then hide/show according to user selected, or load on click with an ajax, of course these are both by way of JS

Comment: I tried it,  as you can see in my php code it was arrayed

Comment: @CharlieSheather can you try implementing or showing it to me by using javascript?

Comment: [Related chat room with additional information](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31159/room-for-vistas-show-sub-checkbox-question)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you had in mind?

I've created two PHP arrays: one containing all of the tests and one containing all of the topics. First, we iterate through the tests array and print out each item. Inside of each iteration, we loop through the topics and print out each item (making sure that every element is given a unique ID).

Once the HTML has been generated, we use jQuery to hide the fieldsets which contain the topics for each test. We then attach a click handler to each of the test checkboxes, which hides or reveals the nested topics.

Obviously, your $tests array will be populated by the results of your database query, as your original code illustrates. I've hard-coded mine for demonstration purposes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Medical Stuff</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Medical Stuff</h1>

    <?php
      $tests = array(
        "Vital Signs",
        "Neuro-Psychological",
        "Laboratory",
        "Radiology",
        "Ultrasound",
        "Audiometry",
        "Optometry",
        "ECG",
        "Treadmill",
        "Dental",
        "Physical Examination",
        "Pediatrics",
        "MRI"
      );
      $topics = array(
        "Complete Blood Count",
        "Blood Typing",
        "Urinalysis",
        "RPR/TPHA",
        "Hepatitis B screening",
        "Fasting Blood Sugar",
        "Creatinine",
        "Total Cholesterol(Low Cholesterol, High Cholesterol)",
        "Triglyceride",
        "VLDL",
        "Blood Uric Acid",
        "Anti-HAV Igm Screening",
        "Anti HBaAg",
        "Drug & Alcohol Test",
        "Stool Culture"
      );
      $tests_length = count($tests);
      $topics_length = count($topics);
    ?>

    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Tests</legend>

        <?php
          // Tests
          for ($i = 0; $i < $tests_length; $i++) {

            $test_value = $i + 1;
            $test_id = "test_" . $test_value;

            print '<div>';
            print '<input type="checkbox" class="test" id="' . $test_id . '" value="' . $test_value . '">';
            print '<label for="' . $test_id . '">' . $tests[$i] . '</label>';

            // Nested topics
            print '<fieldset class="topics">';

            for ($ii = 0; $ii < $topics_length; $ii++) {

              $topic_value = $ii + 1;
              $topic_id = $test_id . "_topic_" . $topic_value;

              print '<div>';
              print '<input type="checkbox" class="topic" id="' . $topic_id . '" value="' . $topic_value . '">';
              print '<label for="' . $topic_id . '">' . $topics[$ii] . '</label>';
              print '</div>';
            }

            print '</fieldset>';
            print '</div>';
          }
        ?>

      </fieldset>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $(".topics").hide();

        $(".test").on('click', function(e){
          var topics = $(this).nextAll('.topics');

          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            topics.show();
          } else {
            topics.hide();
          }
        });

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code ends up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: That's great, but I rather keep my php code which is object oriented, what I mean that it is arrayed is that by name="test[]" based on the post above, but really your work is great I might use it for my other work and project.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this, in my opinion, is to pre load all of the check boxes, hide them and then show them as needed with some javascript.

I will how you how this could work with some javascript.

Here is the basic idea of the javascript and accompanying html;

Html

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="laboratory-test" value="1">Laboratory</label>
<!-- Container for the set of sub checkboxes, hidden on load -->
<div id="laboratory-toggle" style="display:none;">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="1">Complete Blood Count</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="2">Blood Typing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="3">Urinalysis</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="4">RPR/TPHA</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="5">Hepatitis B screening</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="6">Fasting Blood Sugar</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="7">Creatinine</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="8">Total Cholesterol(Low Cholesterol, High Cholesterol)</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="9">Triglyceride</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="10">VLDL</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="11">Blood Uric Acid</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="12">Anti-HAV Igm Screening</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="13">Anti HBaAg</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="14">Drug &amp; Alcohol Test</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="15">Stool Culture</label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//the checkbox that controls the hide/show
var controlbox = document.querySelector('input[name="laboratory-test"]');

//the container of the sub-checkboxes
var subboxes = document.querySelector('#laboratory-toggle');

// attach to the change event of the controlling checkbox
controlbox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    // if it is checked after the change
    if (this.checked) {
        // display the subboxes
        subboxes.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        // if not checked hide the subboxes
        subboxes.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

And a link to a working example.
http://jsfiddle.net/oc9p3a2h/3/

I'm happy to further explain if needed. And if this needs to work with multiple sets of sub checkboxes, happy to show you how that could work too.

Edit: This is using the exact same technique as MarkPlewis, if you need a hand with the php on how to produce the html I have written above, let me know.

Comment: This is nice, but as you can see  my main checkbox are bind :(

Comment: $d1= '<input type="checkbox" name="test[]"
     value="'.$mtn.'">'.$mtn.'<br>';
    echo $d1;

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by bind?

Comment: as you can see in my above php code my main checkbox, is already combined into 1

Comment: I see. Are we able to change the php? Can you add more of your php code to your question so I can see exactly what going on?

Comment: Ok, I'll post another question about this, but it is sorta different

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557981/undefined-index-checkbox here's my new post, hope you check out :D

Comment: Vista - you other question got marked as a duplicate, but the fix for the other question is to change line 103 to "if (isset($_POST['checkbox']) && $_POST['checkbox'] == 3) {". What this code means it first, check if the checkbox index is set in the $_POST array, and only if it is set, check the value of it.